# iOS Simulator scaling as iPhone 4s?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Normally when I create an XCode project and run it the iPhone simulator looks normal, here's a picture: [image: normal image]

This time I have used a Parse Starter Project, so that I can implement parse in my app, but for some reason it is scaled down to what seems to be an iPhone 4s, which looks like this: [image]

If I go to any other project the simulator looks normal, but when I run the Parse Starter Project the simulator does the iPhone 4s scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have forgotten to give your project a launch screen (e.g. *LaunchScreen.storyboard*). The presence of this is what tells the runtime that your app runs natively on the 6 / 6 Plus. Without it, as you have rightly deduced, you are running in "zoomed" mode.